# Adding Acronyms

Tags: overleaf

Why my code is printing only 2 Acronyms:

```
%*******************************************************
% Acronyms
%*******************************************************

\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Acronyms}{Acronyms}
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}
\chapter*{Acronyms}

%\section{List of Acronyms}
% Insert your acronyms here
\begin{acronym}[API]

  \acro{DRY}{Don't Repeat Yourself}
  \acro{AET}{Atomic Event Trees}
  \acro{API}{Application Programming Interface}
  \acro{UML}{Unified Modeling Language} 
  
\end{acronym}

\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? please make your codesnippet be compilable resulting in your issue ...

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your error—I see all four acronyms, not just two. I'm assuming you're using the `scrbook` class and some package like `\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}`. As Mensch mentioned, you're most likely to get an answer if you edit your question so that your code snippet will run on its own—that is, it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.